# Can't exit the script when using 'keyboard' package in Python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import keyboard

def onEsc(e):
    if e.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN and e.name == 'esc':
        print("Goodbye")
        exit(1)


keyboard.on_press_key('esc', onEsc)

while True:
    None
```

I get this weird error - when pressing 'esc', it prints but doesn't exit.
Then, on next press of 'esc', it doesn't print at all.
I checked this in debug, and it seems that it leads to a sort of exception that gets caught, but I wasn't able to udnerstand the source code entirely.

*It doesn't make a difference here if I use 'sys.exit(1)' instead

Comment: What "sort of exception" does it lead to?

Comment: exit(1) will lead to an exit with some "problem". have you tried exit(0)?

Comment: Must be a thread related issue. You could use `while running == True:` and set running to `False` in `onEsc`